# Zend 1.11.11 Doctrine 2.1.2 initialising of associative proxy entities

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am having this strange issue with an associative entity being a proxy class and its methods always returning null. I hope someone can shed a little light on the subject because it's driving me insane.

I am calling this code:

```
$arrRoleResources = $em->getRepository("AJFIT\Entity\UserRoleResources")->findAll();    

foreach($arrRoleResources as $roleResource) {
       $name = $roleResource->getRoleFk()->getName();   
}
```

The $name will always be null even though when I debug the code it initializes the proxy class and the $_identifier is with the correct primary key.

UserRoleResources Entity:

```
namespace AJFIT\Entity;
/** 
 * UserRoleResources 
 * * @Table(name="user_role_resources") 
 * * @Entity(repositoryClass="AJFIT\Repository\UserRoleResources") 
 */ 
class UserRoleResources {     
   /**    
    * @var UserRoles    
    *    
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRoles")    
    * @JoinColumn(name="role_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")    
    *     
    */     

    private $roleFk;
    /**    
     * Get roleFk    
     *    
     * @return UserRoles $roleFk    
     */     

    public function getRoleFk()    {        
         return $this->roleFk;    
    } 
}
```

UserRole Entity:

```
namespace AJFIT\Entity;  

/**  
 * UserRoles  
 * * @Table(name="user_roles")  
 * * @Entity(repositoryClass="AJFIT\Repository\UserRoles")  
 */ 
 class UserRoles {     

     /**     
      * @var string $name    
      *
      * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)     
      */     

     private $name;      

     /**     
      * @var integer $pk     
      *     
      * @Column(name="pk", type="integer")     
      * @Id     
      * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")     
      */     

      private $pk;      

      /**     
       * Get name     
       *     
       * @return string $name     
       */     

       public function getName()     {         
           return $this->name;     
       } 
 }
```

I have followed the zf-boilerplate precompiled example, and i am able to post my config if required.

Comment: Does your repository actually return any UserRoleResources?

Comment: Yes it does, the UserRoleResources are populated fully, and the RolesFk is populated with a proxy entity. When i try to retrieve the 'name' field by:- $name = $roleResource->getRoleFk()->getName(), even thought the code steps through to the actual entity ( getName() method ) the $name valiable in the calling code becomes null, when i have enough points i'll post my debugging screenshot, only 2 to go.

Comment: I found this problem that seems to be very similar to my problem:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599007/lazy-loading-properties-not-loading-in-doctrine-2-0 where do i set fetch="EAGER??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your annotations look a little wrong. Try fixing these up...

#### Class annotation

Lose the extra asterisks.

```
/** 
 * UserRoleResources 
 * 
 * @Table(name="user_role_resources") 
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="AJFIT\Repository\UserRoleResources") 
 */ 
class UserRoleResources {
```

#### Property annotation

Place the docblocks directly above the properties (no blank lines)

```
/**    
 * @var UserRoles    
 *    
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRoles")    
 * @JoinColumn(name="role_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")    
 */     
private $roleFk;
```

Comment: @Andrew Your `@JoinColumn` syntax is incorrect in [`UserRoleResources`](https://github.com/andyfenna/AJF-IT/blob/master/library/AJFIT/Entity/UserRoleResources.php). There is no `@JoinColumns` (plural) annotation

Comment: thanks for your help, I have resolved this problem with in entity but this is still a problem, on line 60 of library/AJFIT/ACL/Factory.php, $test = $roleFk->getName() returns null when this should be the name of the role. Any suggestions???

Comment: @Andrew why have you changed your `targetEntity` references to fully qualified namespaces. You need only use the class name when working within the same namespace

Comment: I did not now that, thanks for the tip, i'll change the entities now. Thanks