# Symfony2 and Doctrine: proxy class does not lazy load entity fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, twig

I have three relevant entities in my application with a oneToMany relation: one "Aufwand" belongs to one "Aufgabe", which belongs to one "Version". At some point in the controller, I write:

```
$Aufwand['version'] = $Aufwand->getAufgabe()->getVersion();
```

and pass that to the Twig template with:

```
return $this->render('XXX:Aufwand:index.html.twig', array('Aufwand' => $Aufwand));
```

"Version" has a String attribute "nummer" which I try to access in my Template using

```
{{ Aufwand.version.nummer }}
```

but it prints nothing, same for all other attributes of "Version" - but I checked and `Aufwand.version` alone is really an `XXXXVersionProxy` - Object, as it should be. So apparently the "Lazy-Loading" from Doctrine does not really happen.

This is the Mapping information in "Version.orm.yml":

```
XXX\Entity\Version:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: XXX\Repository\VersionRepository
    table: version

    id: 
        Projekt:
            associationKey: true
        nummer:
            type: string
            length: 20
        
    fields:
        beschreibung:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        faktor: 
            type: decimal
            precision: 2
            scale: 1

    uniqueConstraints:
        version_nr_unique:
           columns: nummer
        
    oneToMany:
        Aufgaben:
            targetEntity: Aufgabe
            mappedBy: Version
                    
    manyToOne:
        Projekt:
            targetEntity: Projekt
            inversedBy: Versionen
            joinColumn:
                name: projekt_nummer
                referencedColumnName: nummer
```

and in "Aufgabe.orm.yml":

```
XXX\Entity\Aufgabe:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: XXX\Repository\AufgabeRepository
    table: aufgabe
    
    id: 
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 40
        beschreibung:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        faktor: 
            type: decimal
            precision: 2
            scale: 1
        soll_aufwand:
            type: integer
    
    oneToMany:
        Aufwaende:
            targetEntity: Aufwand
            mappedBy: Aufgabe
    
    manyToOne:
    
        Kategorie:
            targetEntity: Kategorie
            inversedBy: Aufgaben
            joinColumn:
                name: kategorie_id
                nullable: false
                referencedColumnName: id
    
        Projekt:
            targetEntity: Projekt
            inversedBy: Aufgaben
            joinColumn:
                name: projekt_nummer
                referencedColumnName: nummer
                nullable: true
                 
        Version:
            targetEntity: Version
            inversedBy: Aufgaben
            joinColumn:
                name: version_nummer
                nullable: true
                referencedColumnName: nummer
```

The getters and setters in "Version" and "Aufgabe" are standard "get{Attribute}()", the attributes themselves are private. I have already tried clearing the metadata-cache and dumping `$Aufwand->getAufgabe()->getVersion() // also plus ->getNummer()` in the controller, everything seems to be right there. And in the Database Table the "Aufwand" has an "Aufgabe" which has a "Version" which should give me its "nummer" ...

I'm using PHP Symfony 2.0.16 with Doctrine 2 on a PostgreSQL Database, any hint where to look for an error would be much appreciated. I guess it could be in the Twig template but I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599007/lazy-loading-properties-not-loading-in-doctrine-2-0?rq=1 with a similar problem and a Workaround using `fetch: EAGER` in the "manyToOne"-definition

Answer (score 0):

why not just pass $Aufwand to the template and do:

```
{{Aufwand.aufgabe.version.number}}
```

That should work from the view.